# Lable control in argument

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am trying to send massage and changing the color of Labels.

```
private void updateStatus(string massageText, Label label)
{
    txtStatus.Text = massageText;
    label.BackColor = Color.Red;
 }
```

when i try to apply this;

```
updateStatus("Level-1 Complete", Label1);
updateStatus("Level-2 Complete", Label2);
```

it give error of

> The best overloaded method match for 'Taal.Form1.updateStatus(string, System.Windows.Forms.Label)' has some invalid arguments D:\Taal\Taal\Form1.cs"

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: What is the complete error msg

Comment: Why don't you post whole exception message? You've omitted the most interesting part which says what was it expecting and what it found

Comment: Full Error Massage is : The best overloaded method match for 'Taal.Form1.updateStatus(string, System.Windows.Forms.Label)' has some invalid arguments D:\Taal\Taal\Form1.cs

Comment: @Braheen You better edit your question and put the full error message in it, instead of in the comments.

Comment: @Braheen If you move your mouse over `Label1` or `Label2`, you should see a tooltip message. The tooltip should say `class System.Windows.Forms.Label` or similar.

Comment: Well then, it seems like you `Label1` is not `System.Windows.Forms.Label`. Could you please tell us what type is it?

Comment: @Braheen, what is the type of `Label1` is it normal win form label or some third party one ?

Comment: oh yes! this is my fault. Actually Label was in Status bar so it is not simple label, it is "ToolStripLabel". Thanks of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with, below method can be reused for any form control

```
private void updateStatus(string massageText, System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
{
    txtStatus.Text = massageText;
    control.BackColor = Color.Red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually my label was on Status Bar So with the help from comments i have correct it. Thanks

```
private void updateStatus(string massageText,ToolStripLabel label)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = massageText;
            label.BackColor = Color.Red;


        }
```